# A camera shake effect for SpriteKit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

Does anyone know some out of the box libraries that might provide effects such as camera shake to an `SKNode`?

If not is there an easy way to implement a camera shake using actions?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found an elegant method using SKAction, that make shake your node. For example, with an horizontal shake:

```
-(void)shake:(NSInteger)times {
    CGPoint initialPoint = self.position;
    NSInteger amplitudeX = 32;
    NSInteger amplitudeY = 2;
    NSMutableArray * randomActions = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0; i<times; i++) {
        NSInteger randX = self.position.x+arc4random() % amplitudeX - amplitudeX/2;
        NSInteger randY = self.position.y+arc4random() % amplitudeY - amplitudeY/2;
        SKAction *action = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(randX, randY) duration:0.01];
        [randomActions addObject:action];
    }
    
    SKAction *rep = [SKAction sequence:randomActions];
    
    [self runAction:rep completion:^{
        self.position = initialPoint;
    }];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Almost 10 years later, I came accross this request and found my own anwer. But now we have a new language, so let's translate it!

```
extension SKNode {
    func shake(times: Int, amplitude: CGSize, duration: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        guard times > 0 else { return }
        let initialPosition = self.position
        var randomActions: [SKAction] = []
        let stepDuration = duration / Double(times)
        for _ in 0..<times {
            let randX = self.position.x + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amplitude.width))) - amplitude.width/2
            let randY = self.position.y + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amplitude.height))) - amplitude.height/2
            randomActions.append(
                SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: randX, y: randY), duration: stepDuration)
            )
        }
        self.run(SKAction.sequence(randomActions)) {
            self.position = initialPosition
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cool. I will try this and see how much better it is than what I am doing currently.

Comment: wow, this works really well, wish I could up vote twice because it also helped with some FPS issues since I could clear my the clutter in my update statement.

Comment: This doesn't work for me i get the error: Animating the position of a SKScene has no effect. - any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Same result with user1216855, I no longer can see the shake effect from this code. I think iOS7.1 did some update to it and it no longer works. How to fix?

Comment: @Rocotilos I'm not in front of my code, but I think you tried to animate the scene. Did you try on a simple subnode?

Comment: Yep I just able to make it work, I added a dummy SKNode and added all the background sprites into it and animate the dummy node instead. Works. :D

Answer (score 14):

The shake method in the accepted answer has a **caveat** - it can only be applied to nodes that do not have their x,y coordinates being modified by other running SKActions. This is because we reset the node's position to its initial position after the shake completes.

If you want a shake action that works also with other SKAction's that modify the shaking node's position (x or y coordinates) in sequence/parallel, you need to add a reverse action of the random shakes you are applying.

A Swift extension for reference:

```
extension SKAction {
class func shake(duration:CGFloat, amplitudeX:Int = 3, amplitudeY:Int = 3) -> SKAction {
    let numberOfShakes = duration / 0.015 / 2.0
    var actionsArray:[SKAction] = []
    for index in 1...Int(numberOfShakes) {
        let dx = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amplitudeX))) - CGFloat(amplitudeX / 2)
        let dy = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amplitudeY))) - CGFloat(amplitudeY / 2)
        let forward = SKAction.moveByX(dx, y:dy, duration: 0.015)
        let reverse = forward.reversedAction()
        actionsArray.append(forward)
        actionsArray.append(reverse)
    }
    return SKAction.sequence(actionsArray)
}
}
```

Note that this modification does not require the node to be passed in as an argument

Answer (score 7):

If you already using Swift you can use following code ...

```
let shake = SKAction.shake(node.position, duration: 0.3)
node.runAction(shake)
```

or for a more intense shake you can configure the amplitude as well

```
let shake = SKAction.shake(node.position, duration: 0.3, amplitudeX: 12, amplitudeY: 3)
node.runAction(shake)
```

here is the extension ....

```
extension SKAction {
    class func shake(initialPosition:CGPoint, duration:Float, amplitudeX:Int = 12, amplitudeY:Int = 3) -> SKAction {
        let startingX = initialPosition.x
        let startingY = initialPosition.y
        let numberOfShakes = duration / 0.015
        var actionsArray:[SKAction] = []
        for index in 1...Int(numberOfShakes) {
            let newXPos = startingX + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amplitudeX))) - CGFloat(amplitudeX / 2)
            let newYPos = startingY + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amplitudeY))) - CGFloat(amplitudeY / 2)
            actionsArray.append(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(newXPos, newYPos), duration: 0.015))
        }
        actionsArray.append(SKAction.moveTo(initialPosition, duration: 0.015))
        return SKAction.sequence(actionsArray)
    }
}
```

credits goes to [Stephen Haney](http://www.thinkingswiftly.com/camera-shake-with-spritekit-in-swift/) for the implementation I just moved it into an extension

Comment: Thanks for doing that!  My code was based off the marked answer in this thread, so we've officially come full circle ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to shake the whole scene, here's a version of Rob's answer written in Swift:

```swift
    func sceneShake(shakeCount: Int, intensity: CGVector, shakeDuration: Double) {
        let sceneView = self.scene!.view! as UIView
        let shakeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")

        shakeAnimation.duration = shakeDuration / Double(shakeCount)
        shakeAnimation.repeatCount = Float(shakeCount)
        shakeAnimation.autoreverses = true
        shakeAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: sceneView.center.x - intensity.dx, y: sceneView.center.y - intensity.dy))
        shakeAnimation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: sceneView.center.x + intensity.dx, y: sceneView.center.y + intensity.dy))

        sceneView.layer.add(shakeAnimation, forKey: "position")
      }
```

I include this function in an SKScene child class.  Here's an example invocation:

```swift
    sceneShake(shakeCount: 3, intensity: CGVector(dx: shakeIntensity, dy: shakeIntensity), shakeDuration: shakeDuration)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the method I use. Hope it helps. Modify it as you see fit.

```
-(void)shakeScreenFor:(int)numberOfShakes withIntensity:(CGVector)intensity andDuration:(CGFloat)duration{
    UIView *sceneView = self.scene.view;
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [animation setDuration:(duration/numberOfShakes)];
    [animation setRepeatCount:numberOfShakes];
    [animation setAutoreverses:YES];
    [animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake([sceneView center].x - intensity.dx, [sceneView center].y - intensity.dy)]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake([sceneView center].x + intensity.dx, [sceneView center].y + intensity.dy)]];
    [[sceneView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

Comment: This worked nicely in my game for slamming something into the screen with the values `[self shakeScreenFor:2 withIntensity:CGVectorMake(2, 2) andDuration:0.1];`

Comment: This WORKS! I like this. Voted up. THanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version of answer from @Benzi:

```
func shake(duration: Double, amplitudeX: CGFloat = 3, amplitudeY: CGFloat = 3) -> SKAction {
    let numberOfShakes = duration / 0.015 / 2.0
    var actionsArray:[SKAction] = []
    for _ in 1...Int(numberOfShakes) {
        let dx = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amplitudeX))) - CGFloat(amplitudeX / 2)
        let dy = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(amplitudeY))) - CGFloat(amplitudeY / 2)
        let forward = SKAction.moveBy(x: dx, y:dy, duration: 0.015)
        let reverse = forward.reversed()
        actionsArray.append(forward)
        actionsArray.append(reverse)
    }
    return SKAction.sequence(actionsArray)
}
```

Comment: Note don't use this on the scene or you will get: "Animating the position of a SKScene has no effect." You will need to run the action on a parent node which contains all the other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)screen_shake
 {
   if (shake)
   {
    current_number_of_shakes++;

    float randx = (float)[self randomValueBetween:1 and:90]/50.0f;

    if ([self randomValueBetween:0 and:1] == 0)
        randx = -randx;

    float randy = (float)[self randomValueBetween:1 and:90]/50.0f;

    if ([self randomValueBetween:0 and:1] == 0)
        randy = -randy;


    camera.position = CGPointMake(camera.position.x + randx, camera.position.y + randy);

    if (current_number_of_shakes >= total_amount_of_shakes)
    {

        current_number_of_shakes = 0;
        move_back_from_shake = YES;
        [camera runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveTo:start_point_before_shake duration:.7], [SKAction performSelector:@selector(shake_done) onTarget:self]]]];

    }




   }

}
```

After some work and referencing ways people do it Cocoa2D here is what I came up with. In your update method you will need to call this method. There are some constants that you can fill in the blanks but I hope this helps for all that need it. Also all the method that shake_done does is update the Bool shake to false.