# SpriteKit Camera Vibration

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I was wondering if anyone knows how to implement a camera effect similar to the Game Over of Flappy Bird. It used to look like there was a quake in the game by moving the camera.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify more, "Game Over of Flappy Bird"?

Comment: If you want a shake effect, you can generate action which moves camera in random directions at random speed...

Comment: hi @Whirlwind, do you know how to move the camera in that way (random directions and speed?)

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21109979/3402095

Comment: If you dig through the post @Whirlwind suggested you will find a very nicely written extension for Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two effective methods that may be useful to you. Either randomly adjust the location of the camera in the `update` function a few times before switching views to the game over scene, or use a shader to zoom in to the current scene and do something similar.

As for using update, I might suggest something like:

Create the following enum and variable:

```
enum ShakeDirection: Int {
    case up = 0
    case down
    case left
    case right
}
var currentShakeDirection = ShakeDirection.up

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    //Set this to true twice every 60 iterations (Since there are about 60 fps for most games, a random variable between 0 and 59 will be less than or equal to 1 about twice per second)
    let switchDirection: Bool = (arc4_random(60) <= 1)
    if switchDirection {
        let rawIndex = Int(arc4random(4))
        currentShakeDirection = currentShakeDirection(rawValue: rawIndex)
    }
    switch currentShakeDirection {
    case .up:
        let x = camera.position.x
        let y = camera.position.y + 1
        camera.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    case .down:
        let x = camera.position.x
        let y = camera.position.y - 1
        camera.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    case .left:
        let x = camera.position.x - 1
        let y = camera.position.y
        camera.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    case .right:
        let x = camera.position.x + 1
        let y = camera.position.y
        camera.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
```

This is only one possible implementation and there are plenty of different options. This will continue indefinitely so I will leave it up to you to set a method to start and stop it as needed.